# Design Pattern for successive method calls with previous method's output as input

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is there an appropriate design pattern for when you have to plug the output of a function as the input to the next one? See the example below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = computeA();
    B b = computeB(a);
    C c = computeC(b);
    D d = computeD(c);
    doSomeWork(d);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the pipeline pattern. There are lots of materials online about it, here is one potential resource:

https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/pipeline/